# CSS Custom radio button not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I use the following code to generate a custom radio button.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mealPlanContainer remove-padding">
    <input id="mp_${mp.hotelMealPlanId}" name="mealPlan" type="radio" value="${mp.hotelMealPlanId}" class="css-checkbox">
    <label for="mp_${mp.hotelMealPlanId}" class="css-label">${mp.mealPlanDescription}</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.advance-search-row input[type=radio]{
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    display: none;
}
.advance-search-row span{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'sagoe-ui-light';
    color: #FFF;
}
.advance-search-row input[type=radio].css-checkbox {
    display:none;
}
.advance-search-row input[type=radio].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:24px;
    height:19px; 
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:19px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.advance-search-row input[type=radio].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -19px;
}
.advance-search-row label.css-label {
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_353a617ca21d6630433b397442362d96.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

this works well in IE 9 upwards but not in IE 8. I think the issue is in the selector which uses to change the background position. Any idea on how to make it work in IE 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious thing I see on first glance is [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked). This selector is not supported in IE8.

If your CSS won't work without the `:checked` selector, then it won't work in IE8.

The best solution I can offer is using a polyfill script like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to add support for this selector to old IE versions.

Comment: when I use the script provided, I can't even see the custom icon which was previously okay!

Comment: Note that Selectivizr requires another library (eg jQuery) in order to work. If you haven't got a suitable partner library for it (the list of suitable libs is shown on the site), then you'll need to either get one of them, or use a different polyfill solution.

Comment: I used NWMatcher as the library but still the problem exists! it's on IE 8.

Comment: I've not used that combination so I can't comment. But Selectivizr does work; I've seen it in action. ie9.js also works. I believe you when you say it doesn't work for you, but I can't really offer any explanation. All I can suggest is to try alternative solutions (ie9.js, or worst case, your custom radios would be fairly simple to implement in javascript instead of css). If you want to keep trying with selectivizr, maybe ask a new question with more details about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There's a bug/glitch/thing in IE whereby a label element can't trigger a checkbox or radio button if it's 'invisible' (`display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;`). The work around is to use some styles so that it's *technically* visible, but not really visible. Setting opacity to 0 and position to absolute does the trick.

If you have an IE only style sheet for versions 8 and older, add this block to it:

```
.advance-search-row input.css-checkbox {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    display: block!important;
    left: -999em;
}
```

Comment: One thing to check will be whether the radio button's 'checked' state is changing when you click the label - that is, is it just a visual problem, or a form behaviour problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use .mealPlanContainer input[checked] + label { //your styling here }
This works in IE8.

```css
body { padding: 2em; }

input + label {
  color: red;
}

input[checked] + label {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="rad" checked />
<label for="rad">What colour am I?</label>
```